# Can a h:inputFile component be internationalized in JSF 2.2

Tags: java, file-upload, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF 2.2.12 mojarra implementation on Glassfish 4.1.1.
I have an upload form including a h:inputFile component. Everything works just fine except that I can not find the way to change the "choose file..." message to an other one.
I can not believe that the HTML5 specs and/or JSF 2.2 does not provide any solution yet, so obviously it is my mistake.
I tried primefaces 5.3 which gives the opportunity to use different language than english on the button of the upload component but I could not style it.

Is there any JSF 2.2 "compatible" way to handle this?

Comment: you can use primefaces fileUpload

Comment: As I wrote I already tried primefaces and it was working except the fact that I could not find the way to style it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try primefaces component `fileUpload` that comes with three buttons on advanced mode : *choose*, *upload*, *cancel*. You can edit the text on the buttons by changing the options *label*, *uploadLabel*, *cancelLabel*.

Concerning the styles, i suggest changing the style in the css class of the buttons, to change colors, or icons.